# How to interpret the org-mode-map key binding?

Tags: key-bindings, modifier-key

From the docs https://org-roam.readthedocs.io/en/master/ecosystem/, `org-mode-map` has binding for `s-Y`

```
(use-package org-download
  :after org
  :bind
  (:map org-mode-map
        (("s-Y" . org-download-screenshot)
         ("s-y" . org-download-yank))))
```

What does `s-Y` mean ? `org-mode-map` displays a number.

```
(keymap
 (8388729 . org-download-yank)
 (...)
```

To which key is `org-download-yank` bound?

Comment: `s-` is the Super key (usually the Windoze key on many keyboards, except for Macs). So assuming you installed the `org-download` package with that `use-package` stanza, `org-download-yank` should be accessible by pressing and holding the Super key and pressing `y`. OTOH, it sometimes happens that the desktop manager intercepts that key for its own purposes and does not let Emacs see it: YMMV.

Comment: @NickD: Please consider posting that useful info as an answer. (Comments can be deleted at any time.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Modifier key `s-` is called "Super". `(event-modifiers 's-Y)` returns `(super)`, which says that `s-Y` uses (only) the `super` modifier.

   See the Emacs manual, node [Modifier Keys](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifier-Keys.html).  What physical keyboard key, if any, might correspond to this logical modifier key depends on your system and hardware.
2. `(event-convert-list '(super ?y))` returns `8388729`, which is the internal representation of the event produced by key `s-Y`.   `(kbd "s-Y")` returns `[8388729]`, which is the internal representation of the key `s-Y`.

   In my setup, and `(describe-key [8388729])` returns the key-description string `"s-Y is undefined"`. But presumably if you use `org-roam` that sexp will tell you what command `s-Y` is bound to in Org mode using `org-roam`.

Answer (score 0):

[Transferred my comment to an answer after @Drew's encouragement, although I think most of it is included already in his (much more comprehensive) answer.]

`s-` is the `Super` key (usually the Windoze key on many keyboards, except for Macs). So assuming you installed the `org-download` package with the `use-package` stanza you indicated in your question, `org-download-yank` should be accessible by pressing and holding the `Super` key and pressing `y`. OTOH, it sometimes happens that the desktop manager intercepts that key for its own purposes and does not let emacs see it, in which case, you'll have to bind the command to a key that emacs *can* see: YMMV.